# При копировании формы Django копируется только первое значение Select

Tags: javascript, django, html-select

Нашёл код, который копирует значение select, но не понимаю как его применить для каждого

```
<form id="form-container" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{add_formset.management_form}}
        {% for form in add_formset %}
        <div class="bird-form">
          {{form.modif}}
          {{form.povername}}
          {{form.number}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button id="add-form" type="button">Добавить</button>
        <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
    <script>
        let origSelect = document.querySelector('select');
        let options = [...origSelect.options];
        origSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
          options.forEach(option => option.removeAttribute('selected'));
          options[origSelect.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected', '');
        });



        let birdForm = document.querySelectorAll(".bird-form")
        let container = document.querySelector("#form-container")
        let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
        let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")

        let formNum = birdForm.length-1
        addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

        function addForm(e){
            e.preventDefault()

            let newForm = birdForm[0].cloneNode(true)

            let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')

            formNum++
            container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)

            totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`)

        }


    </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]